# Erro no metódo ASYNC update com node.js

Tags: node.js

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

quando tento rodar o metodo async update do node, recebo está mensagem de erro

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta

Answer (score 3):

Esta mensagem significa que você têm uma `Promise`, que foi rejeitada(um erro ocorreu) e este erro não foi tratado.

Se você está lidando com Promises através de funções `async`, você deve adicionar um try...catch para capturar o erro da função que você chamou; E você precisa tratar este erro.

Exemplos de como você pode ter recebido esse erro, dado a função:

```js
async function ruim() {
    throw new Error('Ops');
}
```

❌**Erro1 - não tratar:**

No código abaixo o erro não é tratado:

```js
async function errado1(){
    await ruim();
}
errado1();
```

❌**Erro2 - não esperar:**

No código abaixo não se está esperando pela execução da função async, então o erro acaba não sendo capturado:

```js
async function errado2(){
    try{
        ruim();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('ocorreu um erro: ' + e);  
    }
}
errado2();
```

✅**Correto:**

```js
async function correto(){
    try{
        await ruim();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('ocorreu um erro: ' + e);  
    }
}
correto();
```

Note que isso não resolve o erro propriamente dito, apenas corrige o tratamento da exceção.